# emacs starter kit installation error

Tags: emacs, python-mode, starter-kits

I just installed the starter-kit https://github.com/kjhealy/emacs-starter-kit on emacs 24.3. after finishing I have the the following error   *Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/emacs/.emacs.d/init.el': File error: Cannot open load file, python-mode To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the`--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.* How do i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It meant you don't have python-mode, and starter-kit seem to depend on it.

Try `M-x package-install python-mode` inside Emacs, then re-try to launch Emacs

You can also install the python-mode anyother way (on Debian for example, run in a shell

```
sudo aptitude install python-mode
```

Answer (score 0):

python-mode is released here:

https://launchpad.net/python-mode/+download